# How can ffmpeg extract dvd_subtitles to separate file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, subtitles

How can I extract dvd_subtitles from an .mkv file using ffmpeg into a separate file like a .sub or .idx? Or both?

Thank you for your help/advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does not appear to be possible yet:
[FFmpeg Bug Tracker: #2391 - VobSub muxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2391).

For now all you can do with `ffmpeg` is re-mux to MKV or VOB:

```
ffmpeg -i input.vob -map 0:s -c copy output.mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll chime in on this as others may have problems with subtitles that are marked as `dvd_subtitle`.

I have been using ffmpeg to convert my files that were ripped using Makemkv and transcoding them for size. All of the subtitles are outputted as `dvd_subtitle` which are impossible to extract.
What I've done is a bit messy but it allows me to add `SUBRIP` subtitles into my output files. I've just written this and it does not support multiple `.srt` files.  I hope to get this more robust so as to extract and insert the `SUBRIP` subtiles for all that exist.

I have not found an answer as to why ffmpeg is converting the `SUBRIP` subtitles to this `dvd_subtitle` but it makes a mess out of things. I find that my TV doesn't display the subtitles very large but `SUBRIP` are fine.

First, I extract the subtitles from the source video:

```
ffmpeg -i %FILE% %FILE%TEMPSUBTITLE$$.srt
```

Second I copy the video without the subtitles in it:

```
ffmpeg -i %FILE% -c copy -sn %FILE%TEMPVIDEO$$.MKV
```

And finally I re-encode my files adding back the SRT file:

```
ffmpeg.exe -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M  -i TEMPVIDEO$$.MKV -f srt -i TEMPSUBTITLE$$.SRT %GPUENCODE% -vf scale=1920x1080 -crf 30  -c:s copy  -c:v libx264  -codec:a aac -rc-lookahead 8 -bf 8 %FILE%.conv.mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` will extract image-based subtitles into a standalone file. For example, where the 3rd stream is the subtitle in `file.mkv`...

PGS (`.pgs`):

`ffmpeg -i file.mkv -map 0:2 -c:s:0 copy sub.pgs`

VobSub (`.vob`):

`ffmpeg -i file.mkv -map 0:2 -c:s:0 copy sub.vob`

You can use a program such as `SubtitleEdit` to perform OCR on the standalone image-based subtitle file and export the result into a text based format, such as SRT (`.srt`).